# NullPointerException when adding xml file in layout folder

Tags: xml, android-studio, gradle, nullpointerexception

First, I'm sorry. I do not speak English well..

I did adding new xml file in layout folder

[adding new xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtAKt.jpg)

[generated layout file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WeWN.jpg)

but error occurred

[NullPointerException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0flv0.jpg)

I think, it has nothing to do with my java classes.
Because it worked after deleting that layout file.

Here is the detailed error message
Build:

```java
Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Run build:

```java
org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. <79 internal calls>
Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. <30 internal calls>
    ... 3 more
Caused by: com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ResourceException: Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doIncrementalTaskAction(MergeResources.java:364)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:110) <35 internal calls>
    ... 32 more
Caused by: Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ide.common.resources.MergedResourceWriter.end(MergedResourceWriter.java:305)
    at com.android.ide.common.resources.DataMerger.mergeData(DataMerger.java:292)
    at com.android.ide.common.resources.ResourceMerger.mergeData(ResourceMerger.java:384)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doIncrementalTaskAction(MergeResources.java:353)
    ... 68 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.databinding.tool.store.LayoutFileParser.parseOriginalXml(LayoutFileParser.java:128)
    at android.databinding.tool.store.LayoutFileParser.parseXml(LayoutFileParser.java:90)
    at android.databinding.tool.LayoutXmlProcessor.processSingleFile(LayoutXmlProcessor.java:156)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources$CreationAction$1.processSingleFile(MergeResources.java:879)
    at com.android.ide.common.resources.MergedResourceWriter.end(MergedResourceWriter.java:262)
    ... 71 more
```

Run tasks:

```java
org.gradle.execution.MultipleBuildFailures: Build completed with 1 failures. <80 internal calls>
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) <1 internal call>
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. <30 internal calls>
    ... 6 more
Caused by: com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ResourceException: Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doIncrementalTaskAction(MergeResources.java:364)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:110) <27 internal calls>
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267) <7 internal calls>
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215) <4 internal calls>
    ... 35 more
Caused by: Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ide.common.resources.MergedResourceWriter.end(MergedResourceWriter.java:305)
    at com.android.ide.common.resources.DataMerger.mergeData(DataMerger.java:292)
    at com.android.ide.common.resources.ResourceMerger.mergeData(ResourceMerger.java:384)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doIncrementalTaskAction(MergeResources.java:353)
    ... 76 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.databinding.tool.store.LayoutFileParser.parseOriginalXml(LayoutFileParser.java:128)
    at android.databinding.tool.store.LayoutFileParser.parseXml(LayoutFileParser.java:90)
    at android.databinding.tool.LayoutXmlProcessor.processSingleFile(LayoutXmlProcessor.java:156)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources$CreationAction$1.processSingleFile(MergeResources.java:879)
    at com.android.ide.common.resources.MergedResourceWriter.end(MergedResourceWriter.java:262)
    ... 79 more
```

build.gradle (Module:app):

```java
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myplayer"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    // exoPlayer
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.10.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.10.3'

    // Glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'

    // Youtube Extractor
    implementation 'com.github.HaarigerHarald:android-youtubeExtractor:v1.9.0'

    // androidx Recycler View
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-beta01'
}
```

Things I did to fix this error 
 - File-Invalidate Caches/Restart..
 - disable 'Instant Run'
 - delete all class but MainActivity
 - delete '.gradle' folder from the project and was rebuild it again.
 - android studio IDE update (3.4.1 -> 3.4.2)
 - uninstall 'Android Studio' and reinstalling

Comment: Create new project!!

Comment: Thanks, I will. but I want to know the cause of this error. If this error occurs again, I will have to create a new project each time.

Comment: I don't know exactly but there was something that went wrong:)

Comment: Did you try Build > Clean Project.
And is problem fixes when you remove that layout file and build again?